# Apache Mod_Rewrite RewriteRule jsessionid

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to replace the following URL:
http://mydomain/;jsessionid=0000CReXyLJV7rLAl7evJxy1:16h534i?id=abcd1234
into http://mydomain/id=abcd1234 disappearing the jsessionid

I have tried with so many rules, but no way. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "(id=[^;&]*)"
RewriteRule "^.*$"            "http://mydomain/%1" [PT]
```

Comment: Probed but nothing happens. It may be something like:

RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^(.*);jsessionid=[A-Za-z0-9]+(.*)$ $1$2 [L,R=301]